# Add preview actions to peek

Tags: ios, swift, 3dtouch

For some reason this won't work.

I am trying to add preview actions to my peeked view controller. This view controller is created programmatically and does not actually exist in a file.

I have a regular `ViewController`, and I cannot `override func previewActionItems() -> [UIPreviewActionItems]`

It simply does not show up, and it won't compile because it's got nothing to override.

All tutorials I have found are from Swift 2, and I am using Swift 3

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In Swift 3, `previewActionItems` became an overridable variable. Try this:

```
override var previewActionItems: [UIPreviewActionItem] {
    return ...
}
```